# npm run build does not work on GitHub Action workflow but works locally

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, github-actions, workflow

```
---
name: CI Workflow

on:
  pull_request:

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.ref }}-ci-workflow

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    continue-on-error: false
    timeout-minutes: 10
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: "18"

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          cd frontend
          npm ci

      - name: Build code
        run: |
          cd frontend
          npm run build

  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    continue-on-error: false
    timeout-minutes: 5
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: "3.9"

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          cd backend
          pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Test backend code using pytest
        run: |
          cd backend
          pytest tests
...
```

I am building a vue app.

If I run on github actions, it will run for a very long time, past 10 min which is much longer than it takes to run npm run build locally. I have also deployed my frontend to vercel and the npm run build works there.

I have tried to change npm i to npm ci. But it still doesnt work.

Comment: What is your question? Does it work if you remove the timeout? If not, what's the error log? There could be multiple reasons for build time difference e.g. hardware specs, build cache, etc.

Comment: Local you already have all the packages. A build on Github Action always downloads all packages and checks the dependencies. Add a cache mechanism and see if it goes faster. 
[Githib Action Doc](https://github.com/actions/setup-node#caching-global-packages-data) and [Blog Article](https://www.voorhoede.nl/en/blog/super-fast-npm-install-on-github-actions/)

Comment: It doesn't work when I remove the timeout. Sometimes, instead of loading for 10 minutes, it gives an error instead "Error: Process completed with exit code 1" with a very long error message. This is the error log - https://github.com/xuanli286/IS212-g4t1/actions/runs/6439687755/job/17487658767#step:5:22

Comment: @chulin Then do not remove the timeout for now, but implement the cache mechanism. I had included two links in my post.

Comment: @Bademeister after implementing cache, it still gives me the same error - https://github.com/xuanli286/IS212-g4t1/actions/runs/6447865545/job/17504537782

Answer (score 0):

Here is a configuration with a cache. I think it will run fast even without a cache. It makes sense to define a cache.

But if you run `npm run build` with `--verbose` you will see what is:  **Error: Process completed with exit code 1.**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 182704
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at /home/runner/work/IS212-g4t1/IS212-g4t1/frontend/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:144:30
    at Socket.onChunk (/home/runner/work/IS212-g4t1/IS212-g4t1/frontend/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/readBuffer.js:40:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:335:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:308:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:245:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)

Node.js v18.18.0
npm verb exit 1
npm verb code 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Unfortunately I can not help you there, because I have no specific knowhow about vue.js.

**Worklow**

```yaml
name: CI Workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.ref }}-ci-workflow

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    continue-on-error: false
    timeout-minutes: 10
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: "18"
          cache: 'npm'
          cache-dependency-path: frontend/package-lock.json
      
      - name: npm cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        id: frontend-node
        with:
          path: frontend/node_modules
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-frontend-node-${{ hashFiles('frontend/package-lock.json') }}

      - name: Install packages
        if: steps.frontend-node.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: |
          cd frontend
          npm ci            
      - name: Build code
        run: |
          cd frontend
          npm run build --verbose
```